# The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large. using Objectify (DataStore) and not uploading files

Tags: google-app-engine, session, primefaces, jsf-2, google-cloud-datastore

I get the following error.

> com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The
>   request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.

I am using Objectify 4.0 and not uploading any file. I am using the DataStore for my app, but the only item above 1Mb is a `_values` blob in `_ah_SESSION` entity.

The images of the console are in:
http://goo.gl/qP7v7U

I dont know how to troubleshoot the issue and even when the error has been asked before, my problem is that I am not using files and I am actually using the datastore.

EDIT: Testing again, it seems to break in a Delete operation. Here's the log.

> ```
> W 12:37:39.798 /editarContrato.jsf
>   com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
>     at com.google.apphosting.utils.runtime.ApiProxyUtils.convertApiError(ApiProxyUtils.java:42)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:497)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:411)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:856)
>     at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
>     at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
>     at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
>     at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
>     at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.runCallback(RpcStub.java:894)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:904)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.success(RpcStub.java:883)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1130)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1030)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1459)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1280)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2995)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2731)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2900(RpcNetChannel.java:175)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3922)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:669)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:457)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$ClientAdapter.receivedMessage(UdrpcTransport.java:577)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.dispatchPacket(UdrpcTransport.java:386)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.readPackets(UdrpcTransport.java:283)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$1.run(UdrpcTransport.java:100)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:594)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1011)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:892)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:161)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1879)
> F 12:37:39.801 Uncaught exception from servlet
>   com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$RequestTooLargeException: The request to API call datastore_v3.Put() was too large.
>     at com.google.apphosting.utils.runtime.ApiProxyUtils.convertApiError(ApiProxyUtils.java:42)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:497)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ApiProxyImpl$AsyncApiFuture.success(ApiProxyImpl.java:411)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher$1.runInContext(RpcStub.java:856)
>     at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
>     at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
>     at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
>     at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
>     at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.runCallback(RpcStub.java:894)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.rpcFinished(RpcStub.java:904)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.client.RpcStub$RpcCallbackDispatcher.success(RpcStub.java:883)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.runCallbacks(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1130)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcClientInternalContext.finishRpcAndNotifyApp(RpcClientInternalContext.java:1030)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.afterFinishingActiveRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1459)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.finishRpc(RpcNetChannel.java:1280)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.handleResponse(RpcNetChannel.java:2995)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.messageReceived(RpcNetChannel.java:2731)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel.access$2900(RpcNetChannel.java:175)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcNetChannel$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcNetChannel.java:3922)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.client.RpcChannelTransportData$TransportCallback.receivedMessage(RpcChannelTransportData.java:669)
>     at com.google.net.rpc3.impl.wire.RpcBaseTransport.receivedMessage(RpcBaseTransport.java:457)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$ClientAdapter.receivedMessage(UdrpcTransport.java:577)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.dispatchPacket(UdrpcTransport.java:386)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport.readPackets(UdrpcTransport.java:283)
>     at com.google.apphosting.runtime.udrpc.UdrpcTransport$1.run(UdrpcTransport.java:100)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask$Sync.innerRun(AbstractFutureTask.java:260)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.AbstractFutureTask.run(AbstractFutureTask.java:121)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runTask(EventManagerImpl.java:594)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.internalRunWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:1011)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl.runWorkerLoop(EventManagerImpl.java:892)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.WorkerThreadInfo.runWorkerLoop(WorkerThreadInfo.java:161)
>     at com.google.net.eventmanager.EventManagerImpl$WorkerThread.run(EventManagerImpl.java:1879)
> ```

Any help appreciated.

The AppStat error stack

```
@2998ms datastore_v3.RunQuery real=7ms api=0ms cost=0 billed_ops=[]
Stack:
  com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder:276 makeAsyncCall()
  com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy:199 makeAsyncCall()
  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper:82 makeAsyncCall()
  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryRunnerV3:36 runQuery()
  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl:32 runQuery()
  com.google.appengine.api.datastore.PreparedQueryImpl:61 asQueryResultIterator()
  com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.QueryEngine$ChunkingToRefIterator:100 <init>()
  com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.QueryEngine$1:64 iterator()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingQueryResultIterable:28 iterator()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingQueryResultIterable:11 iterator()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultProxy$1:26 translate()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultProxy$1:22 translate()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultTranslator:21 nowUncached()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache:30 now()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultProxy:52 invoke()
  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16:164 toArray()
  co.gov.fonada.planeacion.mb.ContratoMB:67 fillContratos()

 @4218ms memcache.Get real=71ms api=0ms cost=0 billed_ops=[]
Stack:
  com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.Recorder:276 makeAsyncCall()
  com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy:199 makeAsyncCall()
  com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy:138 makeAsyncCall()
  com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceApiHelper:95 makeAsyncCall()
  com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl:475 doGetAll()
  com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl:436 getIdentifiables()
  com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl:59 getIdentifiables()
  com.googlecode.objectify.cache.EntityMemcache:215 getAll()
  com.googlecode.objectify.cache.CachingAsyncDatastoreService:253 get()
  com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine$Round:172 fetchPending()
  com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine$Round:118 execute()
  com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.LoadEngine:258 execute()
  com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.QueryEngine$ChunkingToRefIterator:152 advanceBatch()
  com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.QueryEngine$ChunkingToRefIterator:105 <init>()
  com.googlecode.objectify.impl.engine.QueryEngine$1:64 iterator()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingQueryResultIterable:28 iterator()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.TranslatingQueryResultIterable:11 iterator()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultProxy$1:26 translate()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultProxy$1:22 translate()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultTranslator:21 nowUncached()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultCache:30 now()
  com.googlecode.objectify.util.ResultProxy:52 invoke()
  com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16:164 toArray()
  co.gov.fonada.planeacion.mb.ContratoMB:67 fillContratos()
```

New Edit:

I've discovered a big string in memcache, with _ahs* key, which is supposed to be a session variable. I think thats the variable thats getting too big. The text includes a copy of the HTML for "debug" and copyright disclaimers of a bunch of products.

The whole text is [[clic here]](http://tny.cz/9f31c86e)

This is part of the text:

```
> pppppt6mainAccordion:formPago:dataPagos:modelInputFebrero2016uq~uq~uq~ppppuq~q~q~ �q~!q~$q~%q~    �pppppt6mainAccordion:formPago:dataPagos:modelInputFebrero2015uq~uq~uq~ppppuq~q~q~  �q~!q~$q~%q~    �pppppt6mainAccordion:formPago:dataPagos:modelInputFebrero2018uq~uq~uq~ppppuq~q~q~  �q~!q~$q~%q~    �pppppt6mainAccordion:formPago:dataPagos:modelInputFebrero2017uq~uq~uq~ppppuq~q~q~  �q~!q~$q~%q~    �pppppt%mainAccordion:formPago:dataPagos:ajaxuq~uq~uq~sq~Ssq~Ww#{pagoMB.buttonCrear}uq~Yq~[ppxwDB/formContrato.xhtml @806,33 actionListener="#{pagoMB.buttonCrear}"xsq~Ww'#{pagoMB.buttonCrear}java.lang.Voiduq~Yppxppppxxxtfacelets.ui.DebugOutputsr'com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.UIDebug$2#E�#�  -xq~
?@wt
1427384717777|9<!--

    DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.

    Copyright (c) 1997-2010 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

    The contents of this file are subject to the terms of either the GNU
    General Public License Version 2 only ("GPL") or the Common Development
    and Distribution License("CDDL") (collectively, the "License").  You
    may not use this file except in compliance with the License.  You can
    obtain a copy of the License at
    https://glassfish.dev.java.net/public/CDDL+GPL_1_1.html
    or packager/legal/LICENSE.txt.  See the License for the specific
    language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

    When distributing the software, include this License Header Notice in each
    file and include the License file at packager/legal/LICENSE.txt.

    GPL Classpath Exception:
    Oracle designates this particular file as subject to the "Classpath"
    exception as provided by Oracle in the GPL Version 2 section of the License
    file that accompanied this code.

    Modifications:
    If applicable, add the following below the License Header, with the fields
    enclosed by brackets [] replaced by your own identifying information:
    "Portions Copyright [year] [name of copyright owner]"

    Contributor(s):
    If you wish your version of this file to be governed by only the CDDL or
    only the GPL Version 2, indicate your decision by adding "[Contributor]
    elects to include this software in this distribution under the [CDDL or GPL
    Version 2] license."  If you don't indicate a single choice of license, a
    recipient has the option to distribute your version of this file under
    either the CDDL, the GPL Version 2 or to extend the choice of license to
    its licensees as provided above.  However, if you add GPL Version 2 code
    and therefore, elected the GPL Version 2 license, then the option applies
    only if the new code is made subject to such option by the copyright
    holder.


    This file incorporates work covered by the following copyright and
    permission notice:

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at

        http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.

-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Debug - /editarContrato.xhtml</title>
<style type="text/css">
body, div, span, td, th, caption { font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size: small; }
ul, li, pre { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
h1 { color: #090; }
h2, h2 span { font-size: large; color: #339; }
h2 a { text-decoration: none; color: #339; }
.grayBox { padding: 8px; margin: 10px 0; border: 1px solid #CCC; background-color: #f9f9f9;  }
#view { color: #090; font-weight: bold; font-size: medium; }
#tree, #vars { display: none; }
code { font-size: medium; }
#tree dl { color: #006; }
#tree dd { margin-top: 2px; margin-bottom: 2px; }
#tree dt { border: 1px solid #DDD; padding: 4px; border-left: 2px solid #666; font-family: "Courier New", Courier, mono; font-size: small; }
.uicText { color: #999;  }
table { border: 1px solid #CCC; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; width: 100%; text-align: left; }
td { border: 1px solid #CCC; }
thead tr th { padding: 2px; color: #030; background-color: #F9F9F9; }
tbody tr td { padding: 10px 6px; }
```

Using @BalusC `"poor man's debugging" approach for Listen and debug JSF lifecycle phases`, I found out the error after `END PHASE RENDER_RESPONSE 6`.

Still dont know whats making my app to write these files to the storage.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Solved it. `facelets.ui.DebugOutput` was being written to `DataStore` and `MemCache`. It was created by the PrimeFaces' `<ui:debug/>` tag. The last value I could get hold on was about 900kb. I guess it was growing bigger and caused the error. Disabled it and everything seems to be working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1MB limit applies to all Datastore entities. You need to break down your large entity into smaller pieces.

Note that session is backed up by both Memcache and the Datastore, and both of them have this 1MB limit for individual entities. Make sure that all entities you put in a session are well below this limit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already checked all the entities I create and none is above the 1MB limit, but it seems the ones created automatically (I think by Objectify) in `_ah_SESSION` are the ones giving trouble and I dont know how to troubleshoot them. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't see this large entity because an attempt to save it failed. But your code is trying to save it. Look at the source of your error, and you should see which method in your code tries to do it.

Comment: I added the log. I really cant see where it is breaking.

Comment: Add log statements to your code so you can narrow down which line of code results in this error. There probably just a few places when you call to save entities.

Comment: Ok. Using AppStats I managed to found out the 2 lines giving me error randomly, `ofy().delete().entity(accion).now();` and `ofy().load().type(Accion.class).list();`. Both shouldn't be "putting" anything, since one deletes, and the other reads. How could I troubleshoot this? Thanks.

Comment: Objectify does not use the http session and those stacktraces you posted do not have Objectify in the frames. You can't put data > 1M in the http session; so figure out what's putting it there.

Comment: Solved it. `facelets.ui.DebugOutput` was being written to DataStore and MemCache. It was created by the PrimeFaces' `<ui:debug/>` tag. The last value I could get hold on was about 900kb. I guess it was growing bigger and caused the error. Disabled it and everything seems to be working fine. 
Thanks.